# PHP split emails string with commas in names sometimes

Tags: php, string, email, preg-match, names

I have some old legacy data which contains email addresses in strings like so:

```
$str = 'Joe Bloggs <joe@bloggs.co.uk>, Person, Test [test@person.com], me@email.com'
```

I'd like to split this string into the 3 emails contained within, but you can see some names have the comma delimiter in them, and some emails do not have the RFC specification name at the start. Ideally, the string above would be split into the following array:

```
Array (
    [0] => Array(
        'name' => 'Joe Blogs',
        'email' => 'joe@bloggs.co.uk'
    )
    [1] => Array(
        'name' => 'Person, Test',
        'email' => 'test@person.com'
    ),
    [2] => Array(
        'name' => '',
        'email' => 'me@email.com'
    )
)
```

I'm guessing regex would work here? I've come up with the following, but it only handles a single email address, not a comma separated list (with commas in the name, too!):

```
preg_match_all('!(.*?)\s?[<|\[]\s*(.*?)\s*[>|\]]!',$string,$matches);
```

Thank you!

Comment: If any of the provided solution worked. Please, be sure to accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use

```
(?:,\s*)?(.*?)\s*(?|<([^>]*)>|\[([^][]*)]|(\S+@\S+))
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/PSoyHy/2)

**Details**

- `(?:,\s*)?` - an optional sequence of `,` and then 0+ whitespaces
- `(.*?)` - Group 1 (name): any 0+ chars other than line break chars as few as possible
- `\s*` - 0+ whitespaces
- `(?|<([^>]*)>|\[([^][]*)]|(\S+@\S+))` - a branch reset group matching

  - `<([^>]*)>|` - `<`, then any 0+ chars other than `>` are captured in Group 1 and the `>` is just matched
  - `\[([^][]*)]|` - `[`, then any 0+ chars other than `]` are captured in Group 1 and the `]` is just matched
  - `(\S+@\S+)` - 1 or more non-whitespace chars, `@`, and again 1+ non-whitespace chars are captured in Group 1.

And then use [the following PHP code](https://ideone.com/2BRKMr) to obtain the necessary results:

```
$re = '/(?:,\s*)?(.*?)\s*(?|<([^>]*)>|\[([^][]*)]|(\S+@\S+))/';
$str = 'Joe Bloggs <joe@bloggs.co.uk>, Person, Test [test@person.com], me@email.com';
preg_match_all($re, $str, $m, PREG_SET_ORDER, 0);
$res = array();
foreach ($m as $e)
{   
    $res[] = array('name' => $e[1], 'address' => $e[2]);
}
print_r($res);
```

Output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [name] => Joe Bloggs
            [address] => joe@bloggs.co.uk
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [name] => Person, Test
            [address] => test@person.com
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [name] => 
            [address] => me@email.com
        )

)
```

Comment: This works very well, thank you. However, on strings with just emails and no space after the comma, it fails: "my@email.com,test@email.com". Can it also split out strings like this?

Comment: @seb835 Use [`(?:,\s*)?(.*?)\s*(?|<([^>]*)>|\[([^][]*)]|([^\s,]+@[^\s,]+))`](https://regex101.com/r/PSoyHy/3) if there can be no commas inside the emails. That is, replace `\S+@\S+` with `[^\s,]+@[^\s,]+`.

Comment: This worked for me - I also added filter_var($res[$i]['email'],FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL); to make sure each e-mail had a fighting chance of being valid. Thanks everyone for your help!

Comment: @seb835 Great idea! Happy to help.